# Reduce number of vector field arrows in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector

OK, now that I have figured out how to get my vector fields in QGIS, I can't figure out how to reduce the number of vector arrows on the map. Is there a setting for how many vectors are sampled?

Answer (score 2):

Oh well, I found a workaround by only putting every fifth data point into the csv file with my python program (exports netcdf to csv). Not ideally what I'd like to do, but I was in a hurry.

Comment: You could possibly use the Layer->Query function on your full data-set instead, if you have a suitable attribute field you can use in a filter.